# Function parameter the same in button ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two buttons that are using the same ng-click with different params.

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <button ng-click="takePicture(true)">Save Settings</button>
  <button ng-click="takePicture(false)">Choose from Gallery</button>
</label>
```

No matter what I do, the buttons pass the same param as what is in the first function call.

With a simple controller function for testing, the same param gets logged. In this case, it is `true` for both.

```
$scope.takePicture = function(my_param) {
  console.log(my_param);
}
```

These seems to happen only in Ionic, not with standard Angular. Here is a CodePen for a working example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYBKVQ

**Edit:** Per the solution below, I've included the source of the problem in the code excerpt above. Curse you `<label>`, curse you to heck!

Comment: haha weird. Upvoted, same thing happens if I try to pass strings to the function. I guess just use different function and violate DRY for now.

Comment: It is weird. I also tried passing some random string to a function. You are not insane :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an issue with nesting the buttons inside a label. If you remove the label it works as expected: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojMzLj

```
<div class="list list-inset">
    <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="takePicture(true)">Save Settings</button>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="takePicture(false)">Choose from Gallery</button>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Circle Color" ng-model="data.color">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Stroke Color" ng-model="data.stroke">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: But why? Does label combine buttons?

Comment: @OlaviSau for combining better use fieldset tag

Comment: I didn't even notice that I put them within the <label>. I've had problems with Ionic's <label> before, I should've known that was the culprit. Nobody ever expects foul play from a lowly <label>!

I changed the <label> to a <div> with the same classes to maintain styling. So far, so good!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the issue is with the label as @DenimChicken pointed out, other tags work as expected.

I took a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

I also tested some other cases and it turns out, the label is passing clicks to the first button it finds, in fact it ALWAYS calls the first ng-click, no matter which one you click. The label find the first intractable element, and stops the other events from propagating. This can be changed with the "for" attribute.

When the label is targeted, this happens, the target always gets clicked.

```
<label for="false" >
        <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
        <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="takePicture(true)">Save Settings</button>
        <button id="false" class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="takePicture(false)">Choose from Gallery</button>
</label>
```